# how to get multiple columns from database in one array?

Tags: php, mysql

i want that against each numbers, its call_count and duration are saved in single array.. this is my table:

```
Number   Call_count duration
03455919448    4             14
03215350700    2             35
```

i want somethng like this:

```
foreach($number as $number1)
{
$data=array($row['call_count']<3,$row['duration']<20,1)
}
```

basically i want against each number its count and duration are checked for some values and if they meet the condition, display  output 1... actually i can do it with simple if-else but as i have to train my dataset for neural network implementaion so all rows must be in one array? can anyone please help me out?

Comment: What is in `$number` and/or `$number1`

Comment: use PDO and set the FETCH_TYPE to FETCH_ASSOC which will give you an associative array of columns per row.[link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php‎)

Comment: $number is the database column fetched through sql query and $number1 is the temporary variable as its the syntax for foreach loop.. its like: $l=0;$number=$row['number'];
 $num[$l]=$number;
$l++; @Farkie

Comment: can someone please code it correctly... would be appreciatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I don't understand quite well your code, but:

```
foreach($number as $number1)
```

$number1 is never used in your foreach :

```
$data=array($row['call_count']<3,$row['duration']<20,1)
```

So I guess $number1 is $row.

Second, it would help me if you provide the SQL Statement you are using now.

Comment: $number is the database column fetched through sql query and $number1 is the temporary variable as its the syntax for foreach loop.. its like: $l=0;$number=$row['number']; $num[$l]=$number; $l++;

Answer (score 0):

You could do a query like:

```
select Number, if(Call_count<3, if(duration<20, 1, 0), 0) as checked from tablename;
```

This gives you only the number, and 1 if both conditions are met, and 0 otherwise.

After that, in php do a loop (presented in plain mysql* funcions)

```
$data = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // row will be an array with Number and checked as items
    $data[] = $row;
}
// at this point you will have all rows in one array, with number and corresponding 1/0 in each item
```

Comment: yeah i can do it like that but as i narratd earlier i need this data to train my neural net.. and for that the steps are:1. Initially, for each attribute, a threshold value is assigned.
2. The attribute values of the training dataset are compared with the attribute‟s threshold to declare that a customer will churn or not. Simple if…then …else rules are applied in this process.
3. A model is then constructed for the training dataset.
4. The model is then applied on the test dataset and the results are listed.